# TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm in JSOM (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: javascript, managed-metadata, taxonomy

For building a CAML query including filters by Managed Metadata Column, I need to get the wssid for terms I've only the unique ID.

I found a lot of examples using C# and [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfTerm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.getwssidsofterm%28v=office.15%29.aspx), but now example using the JavaScript Object Model.

Is this even possible with JavaScript?

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
var termStore = termStores.getByName('My Termstore');
var currentTermSet = termStore.getTermSet('f71f5e3f-d393-4ad8-a648-b6ca20f2ce75');
ctx.load(currentTermSet);

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        var terms = currentTermSet.get_terms();
        ctx.load(terms);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function () {
                var termsEnum = terms.getEnumerator();
                while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var currentTerm = termsEnum.get_current();

                    var termUniqueID = currentTerm.get_id();
                    var termLabel = currentTerm.get_name();
                    // How to get the wssid which is needed for filtering in CAML?      
                }                       
        });
});
```

Comment: Don't think wssid is available from the term in the termset, since the wssid is the ID in the TaxonomyHiddenList in a site collection, meaning the same term could have different wssids in different sites. Guess you could make a function like GetWssidsOfTerm, and query the TaxonomyHiddenList.

Answer (score 2):

In JSOM API use [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue.wssId property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312519(v=office.15).aspx) to get the list item ID of the list item containing the taxonomy field value that is encapsulated by the [TaxonomyFieldValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312518(v=office.15).aspx).

Example

```
var listTitle = 'Contacts';
var listItemId = 1;
var taxFieldName = 'Country';

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(listItemId);

ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
         var taxFieldValue = item.get_item(taxFieldName);
         console.log(taxFieldValue.get_wssId());
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
);
```

> Note: a single-valued taxonomy field (`SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue`
>   type) is used in the example

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This is not what I needed, because I don't want to iterate a list, I only have the terms from a termset. At the moment, I do not have a list item like in your code... I added a code example to my question. :)

Comment: @Vadim, do you know why when using a no-markup app page, taxonomy field returns this object: SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue {
$0_1: "MyTermLabel", $1_1: "23875525-01c7-42ad-9a89-bf4e9dd864de", $2_1: 2}? It is better described in my  question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173401/jsom-enumerator-get-itemtaxonomyfield-return-differently-in-no-markup-sharep  Thank you

Comment: @Vadim, How to get the term name by using WSSID or Label from? I want to display term in html page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you were trying to do, but in my case I was able to filter a Managed Metadata field by simply evaluating it as a text field. No need for the WSSID.

For example if your column is called Category and you want to filter the items tagged with "Meetings" you could do:

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Category" />
    <Value Type="Text">Meetings</Value>
</Eq>
```